# While a "Q" char is not entered ask for a number then calculate all the inputs

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I got an assignment to finish: "A method with while, to write numbers until you write F. The result is the sum of the numbers."

Is that weird?, can you show me a solution to this.

Here is what I tried:

```
using System;

namespace DetyratSharp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Number;
            double Shuma;
            
            while (Number != "F")
            {
                Numri = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Shuma = Shuma + Numri;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("The total: " + Shuma);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that is not weird.  It does seem weird to convert a string to double then try to store it in a string var.

Comment: What *specific* problem(s) are you having with "what you tried"?

Comment: "write numbers until you write F" is this 0xF? Or how is "F" supposed to be a number?

Comment: Common, I'm New,  I've edited the question

Comment: Now the title does not match the body or the code.  Thats weird

Comment: Double check your assignment - it looks like you should be checking "Yes"/"No" (to also work on logical operators) not just "F". In either case several implementations were just provided for this assignment - make sure to search more carefully next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Numri` is a `string` so you can't assign a `double` to it. `Shuma` is an `int` so you also can't assign `double` to it. Here is what you want to to do:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Numri = Console.ReadLine();
        int Shuma = 0;

        while (Numri != "F")
        {
            Shuma += Convert.ToInt32(Numri);
            Numri = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The total: " + Shuma);
    }
```